# Oracle Active Dataguard and User passwords

Tags: oracle, dataguard

I support a database that uses an active dataguard physical standby.  The standby database is configured to let users access the read only standby for read only queries and reporting.  We do this allow querying of production data, without risking user queries creating problems with locking/blocking.

The one problem with this, is users are unable to reset their own passwords, because they are going given the connection details for the read only database.  I am trying to think of a way that would allow the users to reset their own passwords from the read only standby, but I am coming up late.  I'm wondering if anyone has dealt with a similar issue has found a work around.

Right now, every time one of the users who only has access to the standby database, has their password expire, they reach out to a member of the dba team and have their password reset manually.

I am trying to find a way to allow users to be, logged into the standby database, but reset their password in the primary copy, without having to give the users the production connection details.

Comment: _"allow the users, who have access only to the standby to be able to reset their password in the primary"_  If they are to change their passwords in the primary, then they will have to have access to it.  You cannot change what you don't have access to.

Comment: “ We do this allow querying of production data, without risking user queries creating problems with locking/blocking.” in Oracle, readers don’t take out locks so using the primary site shouldn’t be a worry if you only grant read to these users. If you want to make sure there’s always CPU available for other sessions then have a look at resource manager.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same "ugly" mechanism Oracle uses to generate AWR reports for standby hosts. Create a database link that actually points back to primary and execute PL/SQL procedure on primary, through DB link.

Comment: That would take some monkeying around to do, but that is probably the best way to do it.  Hell it might be the only way.  Thanks a lot, that's some place to start